# How to make a MongoDB index to speed up key/value subdocuments sorting

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this (simplified):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
    foo: "bar",
    data: [
        {
            "k": "userkey",
            "v": "uservalue"
        },
        {
            "k": "xpto",
            "v": "1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Data subdocument key and values are user defined and unpredictable. I am using this key-value to allow an index like this:

```
{ "data.k": 1, "data.v": 1 }
```

It works perfectly for querying on data subdocument, but I'm having a hard time to come up with an index to speed up sorting. Let's say I want to sort all documents by the "data.v" value from the elements containing "data.k" equals to "xpto", for example:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            dataAsObject: { $arrayToObject: "$data" },
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "dataAsObject.xpto": 1
        }
    }
])
```

It works, but it's making fullscans with poor performance. Does anybody have any idea on how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant, from the docs:

> $sort operator can take advantage of an index when placed at the beginning of the pipeline or placed before the $project, $unwind, and $group aggregation operators. If $project, $unwind, or $group occur prior to the $sort operation, $sort cannot use any indexes.

Once you have an "addFields" stage sort can no longer utilise an index.

You should move the sort stage to be first.